# Use the css() method in jquery to check the style

Tags: html, jquery

How can one use the .css() method in an if statement?

I want to know if the background color is red so i can change it;

```
if($("body").css("background")=="red"){
alert("It is red!")
}
```

Something like that.Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this, however your approach has two problems. Firstly you're looking at the `background` property which is a shorthand that contains the colour along with several other properties which you need to avoid in this instance. As such use `background-color` specifically.

Secondly, modern browsers will report the colour in RGB format. As such you need to check for that, not simply `red` as a string. Try this:

```js
if ($("body").css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
  console.log("It is red!")
}
```

```css
body { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However it's worth noting that listening for specific values in CSS rules is not good practice as it's very brittle. For example, if a browser returns the colour as RGBA, or the colour is changed in the external CSS, then your code will break. A far better and more reliable approach would be to  use a `class` on the body to achieve the result in both the CSS and JS. Try this:

```js
if ($("body").hasClass('red')) {
  console.log("It is red!")
}
```

```css
body.red { background-color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="red"></body>
```